# Implement Picture-In-Picture mode for a video calling app created using Agora.io video call SDK?

Tags: android, ios, swift, agora.io, videocall

I am planning to create a video calling app for iOS in Swift. For the project I decided to select Agora.io as the chosen SDK. I wanted to know whether I can implement Picture-In-Picture mode ?
My use case is, If a user decided to chat with someone while he is on a video call with someone else or the same person he is currently on a video call. So that he can put the remote video preview in P-I-P mode and send and receive chat messages ?